# Как создать таблицы бд после запуска Spring приложения?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Пробую так:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class GlobalDAO implements InitializingBean {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

Syntax syntax = new PostgresSyntax();

    @Transactional
    public void initDB(){
        em.createNativeQuery("create table wall " + syntax.createTableConstraints()).executeUpdate(); 
        em.createNativeQuery("create table chat " + syntax.createTableConstraints()).executeUpdate();
    }


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        initDB();
    }

}
```

и получаю **TransactionRequiredException**

Comment: Я рекомендую вам создавать таблицы с помощью миграций баз данных(типо flyway)

Comment: вы идете не по тому пути. вам надо объявить класс-сущность и репозиторий для него. этого достаточно для автоматического создания таблиц. никаких "create table..." не требуется

Comment: Дмитрий, а вы не думаете, что бывают случаи, когда нецелесообразно мапить отдельные сущности через ORM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе уже посоветовали использовать аннотации или миграции и это правильные советы.

А вот почему не работает твой пример - транзакционная обёртка создаётся уже для готового бина. Т.е. последовательность такая - `new GlobalDAO()` -> `inject dependencies` -> `call afterPropertiesSet` -> `create transaction wrapper`

Т.е. твой `initDb` отрабатывает до создания тразакционной обёртки. Если нужен транзакционный доступ во время создания бина, то надо инжектить менеджер транзакций и создавать транзакцию руками, примерно так

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("transactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager txManager;

...

// @Transactional здесь не нужен
private void initDb() {
    new TransactionTemplate(txManager).execute(txStatus -> {
        em.createNativeQuery("create table wall " + syntax.createTableConstraints()).executeUpdate(); 
        em.createNativeQuery("create table chat " + syntax.createTableConstraints()).executeUpdate();
        return null;
    });
}
```

Ну и повторюсь, используй лучше аннотации или миграции.